# Remove specific app service instance on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

We have an Azure App Service running with 10 instances, one of these instances turns bad approximately 6 hours after a restart. The others are all fine so we are assuming this is a issue with the instance.

To resolve this, we tried restarting the bad instance and then scaling down to 1 instance, hoping that would get rid of the bad instance, unfortunately, it was the last remaining instance.

We tried a scale down followed a few minutes after by a scale up (to the original tier) but picked up the same bad instance. Currently, we have scaled back down, hoping that scaling up after 24 hours will stop us from picking up the same bad instance again but this all seems rather unreliable and convoluted for a production environment.

Is there any way to kill an instance or swap it for a different instance without scaling up/down and back again?

I've tried searching online but can't seem to find anything.

Cheers,

Dan

Comment: Enable health check. The request will not be sent to the unhealthy instance after certain number of failed requests. After an hour, if requests keep failing, it will be replaced: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/monitor-instances-health-check?tabs=dotnet#enable-health-check

Comment: Were you able to find what the issue was and how you fixed it ? I am running in a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately the health check suggestion won't work for us as our /healthz/ready/ response is always "unhealthy", i believe we've logged calls with Sitecore regarding this. @NewBie1234 - i would suggest scaling to a different tier for a few days then scaling back if you're experiencing the same problem

Comment: We tried that, but that did not work. We ended up moving everything to another plan and opened a ticket with Microsoft to kill the bad instance because it would keep showing up. We were not able to get rid of it.